# What are the next 5 numbers in the sequence?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

> It's a simple pattern I thought of. Here it is:
>
> 1,1,1,3,3,6,6,10,10,22,22,44,44,84,?,?,?,?,?
>
> Whoever gives the correct answer and a good explanation gets best answer.

Comment: If somebody gives a better solution I may change the best answer status.

Comment: and what is criterion for "better" solution?

Comment: A better explaination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with S(1) = 1.

To construct the next 6 numbers (S(2) - S(7)), use n = 1 and apply the following formulas:

```
S(2) = S(1) * 2 + (-1)*n
S(3) = S(2)
S(4) = S(3) * 2 + (+1)*n
S(5) = S(4)
S(6) = S(5) * 2 + ( 0)*n
S(7) = S(6)
```

To construct the next 6 numbers, double n to 2 and apply the above pattern again.

To construct the next 6 numbers (84 and your 5 ?s), double n to 4 and apply the pattern again.  This gives:

```
S(14) = S(13) * 2 + (-1)*n = 44 * 2 - 4 = 84
S(15) = S(14) = 84
S(16) = S(15) * 2 + (+1)*n = 84 * 2 + 4 = 172
S(17) = S(16) = 172
S(18) = S(17) * 2 + ( 0)*n = 172 * 2 + 0 = 343
S(19) = S(18) = 343
```

So the sequence is:

1,1,1,3,3,6,6,10,10,22,22,44,44,84,84,172,172,343,343

Comment: Nice, I was going to close this question as I made the wrong sequence, but that was great!

Comment: I guess it just goes to show that you can trick yourself into seeing a pattern in almost any data.  Out of curiosity, what was the actual sequence?

Comment: The actual sequence was 1,1,1,3,3,5,5,11,11,21,21,43,43, etc.

Comment: That would be S(n) = S(n-2) + 2 S(n-4).

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify it into a single formula:

$s_{n} = 2 s_{n-2} + 2 s_{n-6} - 4 s_{n-8}$